# Synchronizing Call log with Gmail

Tags: sync, gmail, call-history

I have noticed a label in my Gmail with name **Call Log**. And it contains the some Call Logs of my Phone. I haven't created that Label. I thought it was because of the Mails synchronization. But the same thing isn't happening now-a-days. The Call Logs label mail box contains the information about only few days. After that it stopped logging the Call Logs information.

I want to synchronize the Call Logging information on my Gmail. How to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the solution and the reason.

I installed [SMS Backup +](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync) application from Market sometime back.
This application syncs the messages, Call logs and Contacts with Gmail.

I installed once and removed. In that time span it sync the contacts, Call logs with my Gmail. Thats why I can see the Call logs label in my Gmail.

Answer (score 6):

Can't shed any light on your current experience I'm afraid. It's possible that Timescape has some sort of feature built in but I have just the app for you. Call Track syncs all your calls to your calendar, including time duration and number (and name if they're in contacts) and will import your existing call log. You can select a specific calendar or label to sync with. Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: I don't see any such option in Timescape.

Comment: @XperiaMiniPro Just a thought, I have no experience with timescape. I hope Call Track is useful to you. Give it a try, though there seems to be a paid app call Backup to Gmail that you might like if it's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This may have been answered by now.
I use SMS Backup+ noticed the same problem.
My Gmail label "call log" stopped logging.
The app settings were no help.
The solution:
Settings, apps, SMS Backup+, permissions, turn on the switch "telephone".
I'm on android nougat and one has to provide more permissions.
Hope this helps.